# Sequel::AdapterNotFound while trying to run Ruby On Rails application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sequel

I'm trying to get a project going on my system. I imported the source code via GITHub, and am running it locally with WEBrick. When I do, the following error is printed:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.8 application starting on 0.0.0.0:3000
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': LoadError: 126: Det går inte att hitta den angivna modulen(*Translation: Cannot find the given module*.)   - C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32/lib/1.9/mysql_api.so (Sequel::AdapterNotFound)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql.rb:7:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.15.0/lib/sequel/adapters/mysql.rb:4:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.15.0/lib/sequel/adapters/mysql.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.15.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in `block in tsk_require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.15.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:72:in `block in check_requiring_thread'
        from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.15.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:69:in `check_requiring_thread'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.15.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in `tsk_require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.15.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:23:in `adapter_class'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.15.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:61:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.15.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:119:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails_sequel-0.2.1/lib/rails_sequel/rails_sequel.rb:5:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails_sequel-0.2.1/lib/rails_sequel.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:215:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `block in load_gems'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
        from C:/Users/Soroush/AppData/Local/VirtualStore/Program Files/Git/foobar/projectxt/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/commands/server.rb:84:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from script/server:3:in `<main>'
```

I Googled on "Sequel::AdapterNotFound", "LoadError126", "mysql_api.so" but can't seem to get any valuable information.

I found this page: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ruby.sequel/2645
where someone seems to have a similar problem, with a reply asking if running `irb -rubygems -rmysql` returns an error. I did that, and it gave me an error that said that LIBMYSQL.dll was missing on the computer. I'm not sure if this is any useful, but thought I'd mention it here.

Does anyone have a clue to a solution to the problem, or a direction for me to look in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part is here:

```
LoadError: 126: Det går inte att hitta den angivna modulen(*Translation: Cannot find the given module*.) - C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32/lib/1.9/mysql_api.so
```

The error is being raised by the Ruby MySQL gem, which you confirmed by running that IRB command.  You probably need to add the LIBMYSQL.dll file to the computer, like it said.

Comment: Thanks alot for the response Jeremy! 

I did have the libmySQL.dll file installed, although at the path of C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin

I copied it to the path of C:\Ruby192\bin and voila - it worked.

Again, thanks alot for your help!